# Changing Pattern Lock Clock Widget with a Running App

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm looking to replace the clock widget that appears on the security lock screen (such as while using a pattern lock) with a custom widget, either from a running application or any component associated with it (such as a service). I am not looking to outright replace the clock widget in the Android system, nor am I looking to substitute the lock screen with something like WidgetLocker. However, I have been unable to find out how to program such a thing.

I have seen this accomplished in the [DI.FM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audioaddict.di) and Sky.FM apps, which are capable of replacing the clock that normally appears above the pattern with a custom media controller. The best example I have to highlight what I'm asking is the image linked below, wherein the clock is clearly replaced with some sort of media player controller while the application is running, without the need to modify system files.

If anyone has any insight on this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[Example Image: Image comparison showing the clock normally present above the pattern on the security lock screen, and the custom widget present while the DI.FM application is running that replaces the clock.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmukO.png)

Comment: What precisely are you asking?  Do you want to know if you have chosen the best method, or are you unsure how to apply this method?

Comment: I'm wondering how actually to apply the method. Sorry, should have linked examples to the apps I was referencing. I've been unable to find a way to replace the clock widget without having to actually modify system files, but these two apps are capable of doing it themselves without need to modify potentially critical files.